# Check current time with stop time in if-statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with the if statement in my program. I am trying to check the value of `current_time` to see if it is smaller than `stop_time`.

Example: When the variable `current_time` is `18:36` and the `stop_time` is `19:00` then I want to jump into the if-statement that prints it is "half way". When `current_time` is `18:36` and the `stop_time` is `19:30` then I also want to jump into the if-statement that prints it is "half way". But when the `current_time` is `18:36` and the `stop_time` is `18:30` then I want to jump into the if-statement that prints `it is finished`.

This is my code:

```
profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
conn1 = database.connect(profilePath)
cur1 = conn1.cursor()
cur1.execute('SELECT start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=?', [channel])
stop_date = cur1.fetchone()

if stop_date is not None:
    stop_date = str(stop_date[1])
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    stop_time = time.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    stop_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(stop_time))

    if current_time > start_time and current_time < stop_time or current_time < stop_time:
       print "program is half way"
else:
    print "program has finished"
```

Here is the output for `current_time`:

```
2016-04-01 18:37:37.664000
2016-04-01 18:37:37.665000
2016-04-01 18:37:37.667000
2016-04-01 18:37:37.668000
2016-04-01 18:37:37.670000
2016-04-01 18:37:37.672000
2016-04-01 18:37:37.674000
```

Here is the output for `stop_time`:

```
2016-04-02 19:00:00
2016-04-02 18:30:00
2016-04-02 18:30:00
2016-04-02 18:30:00
2016-04-02 19:00:00
2016-04-02 19:00:00
2016-04-02 18:30:00
```

When `current_time` is `18:36` and the `stop_time` is `19:00`, it did jump into the if-statement that prints "program is half way". When `current_time` is `18:36` and the `stop_time` is `19:30`, it did also jump into the if-statement that prints "program is half way". When `current_time` is `18:36` and the `stop_time` is `18:30`, I'm supposed to get the `program has finished` as the time has passed and the program has finished, but I get `program is half way` when the time has passed. There is something wrong with my code and I can't figure out what.

I want to print `program is half way` when the `current_time` has not exceeded `stop_time` and I want to print `program has finished` when the `current_time` > `stop_time`.

Can you please show me an example of how I can check `current_time` and `stop_time` to see if `current_time` < `stop_time` to print `program is half way` and check if `current_time` > `stop_time` to print `program has finished`?

Comment: You've noted that `stop_time`s are a day ahead of `current_time`? That and either your code has paste error, or the `else:` has wrong indentation. You would only get `"program has finished"` if `stop_date` was `None` currently.

Comment: Also, you could just do `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`, instead of first using `time.strptime` and then converting to `datetime`. And your second `if` could be just: `if start_time < current_time < stop_time`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida heh, beat me to it.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida can you show me an example how I can use `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')` instead of `time.strptime` and converting to `datetime`?

Comment: @user3788310 just like I typed it, `stop_time = datetime.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`. As far as I can see, that's equivalent to what you're doing. My version assumes you have `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida do I have to use something like this? `date = str(time.strftime("%Y") + time.strftime("%m") + time.strftime("%d") + time.strftime("%H") + time.strftime("%M") + '00') current_time = time.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`??

Comment: @user3788310 No, just the line from  my previous comment should be fine, instead of your two assignments to `stop_time`. Ilja's points were much more important regarding your actual problem, mine were just simplifications.